# How do you sum table by columns and return range of sums?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table `Elements/Objects` where columns are elements and rows are objects which can be crafted from the combination of elements. Cell contain how much of specified element is required for the object. It looks like that:

[image]

Another table, called `Packs` contains the list of packs. Each pack contains one or more objects. It looks like that:

[image]

What I need to do is append packs into my first table of `Elements/Objects`. Every pack there should be a sum of elements required for every object of a pack. So it need to look like that:

[image]

What formula should I use for cells with `Pack 1` and `Pack 2`?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use `IFs`:

`=IFS($A4="Pack 1",B$1+B$3,$A4="Pack 2",B$2+B$3 )`

Comment: This is not expandable. The real table consists of hundreds of packs and thousands of objects.

Comment: Then you might be better of with an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).